# As we are writing %like% in SQL to match some details, how we can implement the %like% in gosu query?

Tags: gosu

```
var pp = gw.api.database.Query.make(entity.PolicyPeriod)
```

What is the syntax we can use for %like% which we have already been used in SQL to match elements?

Please help me to find the implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains function with 3 parameters, first the Column, second the input value and third a boolean value to ignoreCase (true for denorm the input and column value).

> Query.make(PolicyPeriod).contains(PolicyPeriod#PolicyNumber, "123A",
> true)

Produces

> [%123a%]
>
> SELECT  FROM bc_policyperiod gRoot WHERE gRoot.PolicyNumberDenorm LIKE ? AND gRoot.Retired = 0

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .contains as mentioned above, and there is also .startsWith() which will do the equivalent of LIKE %text in SQL.